# R Timeseries plot with categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I need some help in R using ggplot2 for plotting both a continuous and categorical variable in one plot. My data structure is as below. The output is from a sensor that measures the processor core temperature and based on the temperature, it outputs an error code. I get the error codes and Core Temp from different tables from a Database and I first merge the data on the Time to get the dataframe below:

```
Time    Parameter name  Value
09/25/2016 12:00:03 Core Temp   78.4
09/25/2016 12:06:21 Core Temp   83.2
09/25/2016 12:07:12 Core Temp   80.5
09/25/2016 12:08:05 Core Temp   79.3
09/25/2016 12:10:22 Error Code  2541
09/25/2016 12:12:01 Error Code  1523
09/25/2016 12:18:52 Core Temp   79.8
09/25/2016 12:22:02 Core Temp   82.9
09/25/2016 12:25:35 Error Code  2541
09/25/2016 12:30:26 Core Temp   81.1
09/25/2016 12:31:45 Core Temp   78.5
09/25/2016 12:38:24 Core Temp   75.2
09/25/2016 12:39:18 Error Code  1523
09/25/2016 12:42:10 Core Temp   79.3
09/25/2016 12:44:08 Core Temp   80.4
```

I can use the ggplot to plot the continuous variable. However, I am struggling to find a way to also include the categorical variable in the same plot. The desired plot is as below:

[image: time series plot]

Below is the code to reproduce the line graph:

```
> data <- read.csv("test.txt",sep="\t",header=T)
> head(data)
                 Time Parameter.name  Value
1 09/25/2016 12:00:03      Core Temp   78.4
2 09/25/2016 12:06:21      Core Temp   83.2
3 09/25/2016 12:07:12      Core Temp   80.5
4 09/25/2016 12:08:05      Core Temp   79.3
5 09/25/2016 12:10:22     Error Code 2541.0
6 09/25/2016 12:12:01     Error Code 1523.0
> my_data$Time <- as.POSIXct(my_data$Time,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
> require(ggplot2)
> ggplot(subset(my_data,Parameter.name %in% "Core Temp"))+geom_line(aes(Time,Value))
```

This produces the line graph. However, I don’t know how to plot the error codes in the plot above. The Y location of the error codes does not really matter as long as it matches the time. I would really appreciate any help. Kindly let me know if any additional information is needed.

Comment: This is unreadable. Please re-format if you want anyone to read it.

Comment: Please run `dput(my_data)` and copy the console output into your question as code so we can easily replicate your code.

Comment: Can someone please help?